# How to run add two "image slideshow" on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I want to run two slide show on same page,

here is the Fiddle of something similar to what I have created :
**http://jsfiddle.net/55KBN/**

I am able to run First slide show but the second is not working, when I click on the second slideshow controls, it make the First one working.

**The reason behind the issue is**, I am using same structure and class name for both slide show, I have given the different IDs to the Most parent DIV of both Slideshows, **BUT the  problem is** I dnt know how to get information on click of user, that on which slideshow User has clicked? and accordingly how to update the slideshow to work for that particular DIV.

Here is my code:
**HTML**

```
<div id="compareImageBox">
@* PRE LABEL AREA *@
<div id="preLabel" class="marginRight">
    <h1>Pre Label</h1>
    <span class="control prev">Prev</span> || 
    <span class="control next">Next</span>
    <ul class="previewImages">
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/01.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/02.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/03.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/01.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/02.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/03.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/01.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="thumbsImages">
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/01.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/02.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/03.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/01.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/02.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/03.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/01.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

@* POST LABEL AREA *@
<div id="postLabel">
    <h1>Post Label</h1>
    <span class="control prev">Prev</span> || 
    <span class="control next">Next</span>
    <ul class="previewImages">
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/01.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/02.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/03.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/01.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/02.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/03.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-full/01.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="thumbsImages">
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/01.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/02.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/03.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/01.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/02.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/03.jpg" /></li>
        <li>
            <img src="~/Content/images/scanned-tmb/01.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    #compareImageBox {
        padding: 15px;
        height: 95.99%;
    }

        #compareImageBox ul,
        #compareImageBox li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            list-style: none;
        }

    #preLabel,
    #postLabel {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 48.6%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #2f3843;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-radius: 15px;
        vertical-align: top;
        /*BORDER SHADOW*/
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.63);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.63);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.63);
    }

        #preLabel > *,
        #postLabel > * {
            width: 99.5%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #compareImageBox .control,
        #preLabel h1,
        #postLabel h1 {
            color: #e2e5ea;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }

    #compareImageBox ul.previewImages {
        height: 86.5%;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }

        #compareImageBox ul.previewImages li {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

            #compareImageBox ul.previewImages li img {
                margin-top: 20px;
                max-width: 530px;
                max-height: 550px;
            }

    #compareImageBox ul.thumbsImages {
        height: 60px;
        width: 47.5%;
        border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /*BG GRADIENT*/
        background: #475360;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #475360 0%, #242f3a 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #475360), color-stop(100%, #242f3a));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #475360 0%, #242f3a 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #475360 0%, #242f3a 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #475360 0%, #242f3a 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #475360 0%, #242f3a 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#475360', endColorstr='#242f3a', GradientType=0 );
        font-size: 0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 15px;
        border-top: 1px solid #1d252e;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        #compareImageBox ul.thumbsImages li {
            display: inline-block;
            border-left: 1px solid #505963;
            border-right: 1px solid #242f3a;
            height: 60px;
            padding-top: 15px;
            width: 14.28%;
            text-align: center;
        }

            #compareImageBox ul.thumbsImages li:last-of-type {
                border-right: none;
            }

            #compareImageBox ul.thumbsImages li:first-of-type {
                border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
            }

            #compareImageBox ul.thumbsImages li:last-of-type {
                border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
            }

            #compareImageBox ul.thumbsImages li:hover,
            #compareImageBox ul.thumbsImages li.selected {
                background: url(../../Content/images/icons/selectedBg.png) top left no-repeat;
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 42px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
                -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 42px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
                box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 42px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
            }

            #compareImageBox ul.thumbsImages li.selected {
                border-left: 1px solid #242f3a;
            }

            #compareImageBox ul.thumbsImages li img {
                width: 35px;
                height: 35px;
            }

            #compareImageBox ul.thumbsImages li a.prev,
            #compareImageBox ul.thumbsImages li a.next {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: arial;
                background: #475360;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #475360 0%, #242f3a 28%, #242f3a 62%, #475360 100%);
                background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #475360), color-stop(28%, #242f3a), color-stop(62%, #242f3a), color-stop(100%, #475360));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #475360 0%, #242f3a 28%, #242f3a 62%, #475360 100%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #475360 0%, #242f3a 28%, #242f3a 62%, #475360 100%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #475360 0%, #242f3a 28%, #242f3a 62%, #475360 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #475360 0%, #242f3a 28%, #242f3a 62%, #475360 100%);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#475360', endColorstr='#475360', GradientType=0 );
                width: 20px;
                padding: 0;
                line-height: 60px;
            }
</style>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
var thumbs = $('ul.thumbsImages li');
var images = $('ul.previewImages li');
var lastElem = thumbs.length - 1;
var target;

thumbs.first().addClass('selected');
images.hide().first().show();

function sliderResponse(target) {
    images.fadeOut(300).eq(target).fadeIn(300);
    thumbs.removeClass('selected').eq(target).addClass('selected');
}

thumbs.click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        target = $(this).index();
        sliderResponse(target);
        resetTiming();
    }
});
$('.next').click(function () {
    target = $('ul.thumbsImages li.selected').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target + 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    resetTiming();
});
$('.prev').click(function () {
    target = $('ul.thumbsImages li.selected').index();
    lastElem = thumbs.length - 1;
    target === 0 ? target = lastElem : target = target - 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    resetTiming();
});

function sliderTiming() {
    target = $('ul.thumbsImages li.selected').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target + 1;
}
var timingRun = setInterval(function () {
    sliderTiming();
}, 5000);

function resetTiming() {
    clearInterval(timingRun);
    timingRun = setInterval(function () {
        sliderTiming();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding new variables to javascript and changing those classes on the other slider in html. Example

```
var thumbs = $('ul.thumbsImages2 li');
var images = $('ul.previewImages2 li');
```

Also dont forget to add to the css those new classes. Example

```
    #compareImageBox ul.previewImages li img,
    #compareImageBox ul.previewImages2 li img {
        margin-top: 20px;
        max-width: 530px;
        max-height: 550px;
    }
```